# Make a DIV tag align center ONLY in responsive mode

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, alignment, media

I have a header with three columns.

```
<div class="thirds">
    <a href="http://www.honey-do-list-services.net"><img src="http://www.honey-do-list-services.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/honeydolistlogweb-handyman.png" align="left"></a>
</div>
<div class="thirds">
    <a href="http://www.honey-do-list-services.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/CheckAPro-1-Ramsey-4-30-14.mp3" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.honey-do-list-services.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/dave-ramsey-endorsement-button-small.png"></a>
</div>
<div class="thirds">
   <a href="http://www.honey-do-list-services.net/contact-us/"><img src ="http://www.honey-do-list-services.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/contact_iconsmhandyman.png"; align="right"></a>
</div>
```

The columns are aligned individually (left, center and right). I need to have ALL of them be centered but only on a small media screen. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

For both Portrait and Landscape mode

```
   @media screen 
      and (device-width: 320px) 
      and (device-height: 640px) 
      and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

     .thirds{
        width:100%;
        display:block;
        text-align:center;
        vertical-align: center;
      }    
    }
```

This might work :)

Comment: I must be doing something wrong with my actual third column. This didn't seem to work, although it looks like it should. This is my thirds code 

`.thirds {
      width: 313px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: bottom;
}`

The site i'm trying to get it to work on is http://www.honey-do-list-services.com. It's the logo, banner button and phone number.

Comment: you've given inline alignment in your img tags <img align="left" src="..."/>  OR <img align="right   src="..." / >

You need remove that.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries are your best bet.
Add this to your stylesheet, the min and max attributes can have any value, this is just an example:

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
  {
    div.thirds 
    {
      text-align: center;/* or whatever property you want*/
    }
  }
```

Really good article here: 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: I think maybe i'm formatting my thirds wrong then? This didn't seem to work. This is the site I'm trying to fix this on. It's in regards to the logo, bar button, and phone number. http://www.honey-do-list-construction.com/

This is the thirds code i'm using.
    .thirds {
      width: 313px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: bottom;
}

I basically need them to be in a line on a big screen and centered over each other on a smaller one.

Comment: The code I provided was psuedo code. I looked at your source code, if you want any child elements(like the image tag) to be centered properly in the media query, you need to set your ".thirds" class to have a  width of 100%. Then you need to add some additional properties and apply them to the image tag(best practice is to add a class to the image tag and apply the styles to that). I know that's a lot but you need to 1) Set your thirds div to 100% within that media query I provided and 2) Set your image tag to (display:block, margin: 0 auto;)